# check with nmcli device wifi if there's an active connection

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm building some code on java to disconnect the wifi in case theres an active wifi connection

To disconnect the wifi connection i use:

```
 nmcli con down id [SSID NAME]
```

But i need the command to check if theres an active connection an if so, i need the name of the SSID Active wifi connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the active connections with this command

```
nmcli con show --active
```

It will show you if there's an active wifi or ethernet connection, if there's no wifi type displayed then there's no active wifi connection.